# For loop in R and append value by creating new column

Tags: r

I have a data-set as follows:

```
  UID     days
-------|---------
  152  | Monday
  145  | Tuesday
  162  | Thursday
  234  | Sunday
```

I have 2 columns in my data-set `UID` and `days`. Now how do I create new column **`is_weekday`** in R and loop through the Days column and add **`1`** if it is weekday and **`0`** if it is weekend.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifelse(grepl("Saturday|Sunday",dat$days),0,1)
[1] 1 1 1 0
> transform(dat,is_weekday=ifelse(grepl("Saturday|Sunday",days),0,1))
  UID     days is_weekday
1 152   Monday          1
2 145  Tuesday          1
3 162 Thursday          1
4 234   Sunday          0
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, here is a `tidyverse` way

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(is_weekday = 1 - as.numeric(str_detect("Saturday|Sunday", days)))
#  UID     days is_weekday
#1 152   Monday          1
#2 145  Tuesday          1
#3 162 Thursday          1
#4 234   Sunday          0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "UID days
152 Monday
145 Tuesday
162 Thursday
234 Sunday", header = T)
```